# Using Db Utils with Karate Standalone jar

Tags: karate

I am using karate stand-alone jar and it works seamless for me.
Now I have a requirement to connect to DB to pull some values from a table for validation.
Has anyone tried using this with the standalone jar or I need to take some other route?
Thanks for help.